# Wireless on my EEE 1005HA doesn't work properly yet there's no additional driver listed

Tags: 11.10, wireless, drivers

Reception is full but it often fails to connect to web pages. Kernel after updating: 3.0.0-15. Router Model is D-Link DIR-615. How can I find an appropriate Linux driver?

The first one (output):

```
    *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:25:d3:5e:e6:b0
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.0.0-12-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:fbff0000-fbffffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8132 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Atheros Communications
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c0
       serial: 00:26:18:ac:ed:e6
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:45 memory:f7fc0000-f7ffffff ioport:ec00(size=128)
```

The second one:

```
   0: eeepc-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: eeepc-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The third one:

```
Linux arno-1005HA 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:50:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 11.10. The wireless card is a Broadcom 802.11a/b/g/n. Will be back with the results in a moment.

Comment: I don't know what a router channel number is. My other notebook works fine. I did download an additional wireless driver for it though.

Comment: ok - you have an atheros 9285.  Please connect via a wired connection and use update-manager to update - your kernel should update to 3.0.0-15.  Also please can you look at your router as per this question and see if reducing your router speed to 54MBs works for you:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/67849/problems-with-d-link-dir-600-and-my-ar9285-wireless-card

Comment: Do you mean "WAN port speed"? It was set to 10/100Mbps. Other options were 100 and 10 Mbps. I set it to the latter. Didn't help. Powered router off and on again. Didn't help neither.

Comment: The driver youre 
looking for is called `ath9k`.  you can ensure it's enabled by running `lsmod | grep ath9k`

Comment: @user34648 - the link I gave you mentioned that he reset his router to its defaults and then created a new user name and password.  Can you try this please?  Are you connecting WEP/WPA/WPA2 etc?  Does it make any difference if you try another protocol WEP/WPA/WPA2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install the latest stable compat-wireless-3.3-rc1-2.tar.bz2

http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Download/stable/#compat-wireless_3.3_stable_releases

open up a terminal

`cd Desktop` or where_ever_you_downloaded_the_file

```
tar -xf compat-wireless-3.3.rc1-2.tar.bz2

cd compat-wireless-3.3.rc1-2

make

sudo make install

sudo make unload
```

OR

you could use the windows driver with ndiswrapper

install ndiswrapper

locate the .inf file

/sbin/modprobe ndiswrapper

One last ditch effort

Wireless (Atheros AR9285) works out of the box, but connection is flaky. To fix, open a terminal and type 'sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-karmic'

PER UBUNTU https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks

Comment: First suggestion did it, had to install "make" first though.

Comment: Good deal, atta-boy, nice job and congrats.